# Ошибка при чтении одной из колонок БД

Tags: android, cursoradaper

Мне нужно получить значение колонки favorite (если "1", то запись добавлена в избранные, если "0", то нет), для того, чтобы добавлять или удалять из избранного. Это все происходит в активити, которая отображает полное содержание карточки.

```
 public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    public static final String EXTRA_POEM_ID = "poem_id";
   .....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tv_Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_Poem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_poem);
        tv_Years = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_years);

        final ImageView iv_heart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_heart);
        iv_heart.setFocusable(false);

        favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_FAVORITE));

        if (favorite.equals("0")) {
            iv_heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
        } else {
            iv_heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_ok);
        }

        iv_heart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (favorite.equals("0")) {
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_FAVORITE, "1");
                    getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(PoemsContract.Poems.URI, poemId),
                            contentValues,
                            null,
                            null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    iv_heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_ok);
                } else {
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_FAVORITE, "0");
                    getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(PoemsContract.Poems.URI, poemId),
                            contentValues,
                            null,
                            null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Удалено из избранного", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    iv_heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);

                }

            }
        });


        poemId = getIntent().getLongExtra(EXTRA_POEM_ID, -1);
        if (poemId == -1) {
            finish();
        }

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(
                0, // Идентификатор загрузчика
                null, // Аргументы
                this // Callback для событий загрузчика
        );

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(
                this,  // Контекст
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(PoemsContract.Poems.URI, poemId), // URI
                PoemsContract.Poems.SINGLE_PROJECTION, // Столбцы
                null, // Параметры выборки
                null, // Аргументы выборки
                null // Сортировка по умолчанию
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        cursor.setNotificationUri(this.getContentResolver(), PoemsContract.Poems.URI);
        displayPoem(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    private void displayPoem(Cursor cursor) {
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            finish();
        }

        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_TITLE));
        tv_Title.setText(title);

        String poem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_POEM));
        tv_Poem.setText(poem);

        String years = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_YEARS));
        tv_Years.setText(years);

    }
```

в строке `favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_FAVORITE));`  ошибка  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`
т.е. работает только блок else (удаление из избранного).

Никак не могу понять почему возникает такая ошибка, ведь в методе displayPoem я также считываю данные таблицы из БД и все работает.

Comment: Вы думаете, кто-то будет разбираться в этих простынях? Добавьте **минимально** необходимый пример кода, а не вообще всё, что есть.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считывание данных происходит в переопределенном методе onLoadFinished.
Для исправления ошибки необходимо перенести слушатель в метод displayPoem.

```
 public void displayPoem(Cursor cursor) {
    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        finish();
    }

    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_TITLE));
    tv_Title.setText(title);

    String poem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_POEM));
    tv_Poem.setText(poem);

    String years = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_YEARS));
    tv_Years.setText(years);

    String favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_FAVORITE));

    if (favorite.equals("0")) {
        iv_heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    } else {
        iv_heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_ok);
    }

    iv_heart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (favorite.equals("0")) {
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_FAVORITE, "1");
                getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(PoemsContract.Poems.URI, poemId),
                        contentValues,
                        null,
                        null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                iv_heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_ok);
            } else {
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_FAVORITE, "0");
                getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(PoemsContract.Poems.URI, poemId),
                        contentValues,
                        null,
                        null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Удалено из избранного", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                iv_heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Это не решение проблемы в вопросе, но хотелось бы поделиться, а в комментарий все не войдет.

В наше просвещенное время есть гораздо более совершенные инструменты работы с данными в Android, в частности [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/): ORM Room, LiveData, ViewModel. Как в свое время CursorLoader был хорошим шагом вперед, по сравнению с работой с базой напрямую, так и сегодня имеющиеся инструменты - 3 существенных шага от CursorLoader.

Новые инструменты позволяют избавиться, в первую очередь, от огромного количества сопровождающего кода, всех этих запутанных ContentProvider и прочих "портянок". Код получается лаконичным и выразительным.
Затем вы выходите на новый уровень взаимодействия, работаете с объектами, а не "сырым" курсором, получаете "развязанный" слой ViewModel и прочие "удобства".
Так же, с появлением в библиотеках поддержки класса [v7.ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html), появилось реактивное взаимодействие с UI-слоем, то есть вам больше не нужно забоится о его обновлении, достаточно просто отдавать команды DAO базы данных на изменение, добавление, удаление и эти действия тут же будут отражены в UI-слое автоматически, с анимациями. Это очень удобно. [Пример](https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/recyclerview-more-animations-with-less-code-using-support-library-listadapter-62e65126acdb)

Подробнее с технологией можно познакомиться в этой [серии уроков](http://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components.html).

Я хочу сказать, что все это действительно стоит внимания и использования, качественно новый уровень и лично я вспоминаю "как страшный сон" все то , что приходилось делать ранее для простого взаимодействия с базой данных.

Comment: Спасибо за советы! Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение. Если я новичек-самоучка и это первое приложение, которое пишу с нуля, в этом случае тоже стоит отказаться от "портянок" или все же помучиться и попытаться понять провайдер и прочее, а потом осваивать новые инструменты?

Comment: @Electra работа с контент-провайдером может понадобится когда, например, вы захотите расшарить данные своего приложения, понимание работы с БД на "низком" уровне тоже никогда не помешает, если вам хочется узнать - ничего не может вам помешать. То, что написано в этом ответе, это так сказать, последние тренды в данной области, которые дают некоторые преимущества по сравнению с прошлыми решениями, писать код легче, а результат лучше, в публичном проекте желательно использовать новые инструменты, а для себя вы можете выбирать все, что вам интересно изучить-практика и опыт никогда не будут лишними